# User inputs a number, and program should surround it with charatchers

Tags: c

This is my code, it works but i feel i could do something different

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Input a number [0,9]: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("*****\n");
    printf("*****\n");
    printf("**%d", n);
    printf("**");
    printf("\n*****\n");
    printf("*****\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Is this the best solution or is there something easier?

Comment: Why do you even convert the input to a number if you only want to echo the string with some prefix and postfix added?

Comment: @EOF im new to C, so what should i do instead?

Comment: Depends. If you expect the input to *only* consist of a single digit, you could declare a `char c;` and `scanf("%c", &c);` a character, then `printf("*****\n*****\n**%c**\n*****\n*****\n", c);`. If you want semantics broadly matching your current version, you'd have to get a string, strip whitespace and echo that. If you want to exactly match your current semantics, you could check all of the non-leading-whitespace input characters with `isdigit()`.

Comment: How do you want your program to behave on input `foo\n`? Currently, your program will exhibit undefined behavior with that input, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to do 1 `printf()` per output line

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    printf("Input a number [0,9]: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if ((n < 0) || (n > 9)) printf("nope\n");
    else {
        printf("*****\n");
        printf("*****\n");
        printf("**%d**\n", n);
        printf("*****\n");
        printf("*****\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    printf("Input a number [0,9]: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if ((n < 0) || (n > 9)) printf("nope\n");
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (i == 2) {
                printf("**%d**\n", n);
            } else {
                printf("*****\n");
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So this is the best solution? I can not do this with while or for loops?

Comment: I feel that a loop here will just make the code harder to read (though it's a very simple code anyway). Version with loop added.

Comment: Thank you so much, one more question if im not bothering you. In case I want to make it so the users chooses the characters that will surround it, for example he inputs + for the surrounding can I do that awell with the loop?

Comment: Yes, you could do it with another embedded loop. However consider breaking the sequence of loops into functions; ie. instead of adding a loop, call a user-defined function (the loop is still there, 'hidden' inside the function).

Comment: How would that loop look like, would it be the char repeating or?

Comment: @Enzor I do not believe that your task is so trivial. Probably you need to do something more comlex.

Comment: @pmg you should use function for this task, not program everything in the `main` as beginnners tend to do.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it a bit more universal way. It will print NCHARS around the number and NLINES lines of FILLER around the number. Any number is covered (including negave ones)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NCHARS      3
#define NLINES      3
#define FILLER      '*'

size_t countdigits(int n)
{
    size_t ndigits = n <= 0 ? 1 : 0;
    while(n) 
    {
        ndigits++;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return ndigits;
}

void printlines(size_t nchars, char ch)
{
    for(size_t before = 0; before < NLINES; before++)
    {
        for(size_t pos = 0; pos < nchars; pos++ )
            printf("%c", ch);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void printfsurrounded(int n)
{
    size_t nchars = countdigits(n);
    printlines(nchars + NCHARS * 2, FILLER);
    for(int pos = 0; pos < NCHARS; pos++) printf("%c", FILLER);
    printf("%d", n);
    for(int pos = 0; pos < NCHARS; pos++) printf("%c", FILLER); 
    printf("\n");
    printlines(nchars + NCHARS * 2, FILLER);
}

int main(void)
{
    printfsurrounded(4);
    printf("\n");
    printfsurrounded(1024);
    printf("\n");
    printfsurrounded(-233445);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hz1eq9

Comment: I dont think it should be this complicated, the numbers are always supposed to be single digit and this is kinda over the top for my level. I feel like it should be with for loops, because the next excercise is to let the user choose the char for surrounding the number.